# Rails 4: find_or_initialize_by and conditional default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a class that builds a relation like so:

```
def assign_vars
  template_variables.each do |master|
    @document.template_variables.find_or_initialize_by(
      name: master.name, tag: master.tag, text: master.default_value)
    end
  end
end
```

So that it will be found if it's already there or built if it's not. My problem is with the `text: master.default_value`. I want to set that only if we're building new relations and *not* for ones found with `find_or_initialize_by`. Something like `text: text || master.default_value`. How can I write that in that loop?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Your `find_or_initialize_by` will only find the records that have `master.default_value` in their `text` attribute.

Comment: Yes I know. I want to set the `text: master.default_value` only if it's an initialized record and not a found one.

Comment: Why does it matter since they will both have `master.default_value` as a `text` attribute? Maybe you only need `tv = @document.template_variables.find_or_initialize_by(
      name: master.name, tag: master.tag)` and then `tv.text ||= master.default_value` and then `tv.save!`

Comment: You can try my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you study the implementation of [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by),

```
def find_or_initialize_by(attributes, &block)
  find_by(attributes) || new(attributes, &block)
end
```

you will see it expects `attributes` as well as a `block`. Attributes are used for finding the record only. So you can pass a `block` to initialize the default attributes during instantiation of the new object.

So, to set default `text` value only if record not found, you might try this:

```
def assign_vars
  template_variables.each do |master|
    @document.template_variables.find_or_initialize_by(
      name: master.name, tag: master.tag) do |t| 
        t.text = master.default_value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks! Thanks also for the concise explanation of the method.

Comment: Although this seems to duplicate sets of information, so that if `A`, `B`, and `C` are saved on create, and `D` is added on update, we end up with `A B C A B C D` and not only `A B C D`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not getting your problem, could you please elaborate a little more?